# QML Coding Style Checker

Tags: qt, coding-style, qml, dsl

I'm looking for a coding style checker for QML code. Something like Checkstyle or Artistic Style. What do people use to define coding style checks for their DSL of choice?

Clarification: I'm looking for something that can be used in build automation not a GUI tool.

Comment: There is a discussion on a Qt list: https://interest.qt-project.narkive.com/RjEOW4BF/beautifier-for-qml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Qt 5.15, a new tool `qmlformat` is shipped which automatically formats any QML file according to the [QML Coding Conventions](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-codingconventions.html).

Source: [Qt 5.15 release notes](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Features_in_Qt_5.15)

Comment: It formats terrible, not according to this  QML Coding Conventions and not adjustable.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know QtCreator works well enough with QML. You can [specify a coding style](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-code-style-settings.html) you'd like the editor to adhere to. Then use **Tools > Reformat File** to format the style.

Comment: That's nice. However I want to automate this (auto-check style on commit, etc). So a GUI tool doesn't kick it, unfortunately.

Comment: Hmmm in that case maybe look for QtCreator plugins? There's an [Artistic Style plugin](http://histomatics.de/proasp.php) for it. You could also refer to this [list](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Qt_Creator_Plug-in_Gallery).

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a new code formatter called `qmlfmt`.

See on github: https://github.com/jesperhh/qmlfmt

Sadly, it doesn't seem to offer a lot of options for now.